# Is every regular paratopological group completely regular?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, topological-groups

This problem is presented as an open problem 1.31. on p.26 of Arhangel'skii-Tkachenko, [Topological groups and related structures](http://books.google.ch/books?id=B785AETmFKEC). Is this problem still open?

Comment: My collegue posed this question to MathOverflow server, however it is still without any answer or comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I already told you at the workshop, [Taras Banakh and me solved this problem](http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.1504). But, surprisingly and converse to that I told at the workshop, the answer is affirmative. This is why is good to write a common paper: if one of the authors is trying to prove a conjecture and another is trying to refute it then one of them should be right. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this problem is still open for many years and seems to be very hard. If you need a reference for this, you can add it, for instance, as "[Rav] Alex Ravsky. A personal communication". :-)